# when I put laptop to sleep, and close the lid, it immediately wakes up

Tags: debian, power-management, laptop

I have new ThinkPad T14s Gen 4, AMD.

when I put the laptop to sleep:

```
echo mem > /sys/power/state
```

it goes to sleep, but as soon as I close thew lid, it wakes up.

When I boot Debian Live CD, then sleep works normally. (closing the lid does not wake up the laptop)

So this does not seem to be HW issue, or BIOS settings. Rather, I suspect some settings on my system, or my kernel. I am using custom self-compiled kernel (here is my kernel [config](https://ctxt.io/2/AADQIAb5Fg))

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: That's a BIOS bug, ask your vendor to fix it. I have the exact same issue and it's reproducible under Windows as well.